# Scalar multiplication well-defined using tensor product universal property

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, universal-algebra, universal-property

I have a question concerning the proof, that the scalar multiplication of a module is well-defined. I guess, that the universal property of the tensor product will help, but I am not quite sure in which way.

Consider the left $L$-vector spaces $A:=\bigoplus_{\sigma \in G} L u_\sigma, B:= \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G} L v_\sigma, C:= \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G}L w_\sigma$ and the tensor product $M:=A \dot{\otimes}_L B$ (with the multiplication $la \dot{\otimes}b = a \dot{\otimes}lb$ so there is a module structure). 
Now I have to proof, that the scalar multiplication $C \times M \to M$
$$ l w_\sigma (a \dot{\otimes}b) := l u_\sigma a\dot{\otimes} v_\sigma b$$
is well-defined making $M$ a $C$-module

I know, that the notation is kind of complicated, so a general idea how to do it generally and how to include the universal property would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are $G, u_\sigma, v_\sigma, w_\sigma$?

Comment: $G$ is the Galois group of a field-extension $L|K$ and $u_\sigma, v_\sigma, w_\sigma$ are just symbols. Don't worry too much about it. I'm more interested in the general case and there is much context required to make sense of the statement.